# array without any duplicate value

Tags: vb.net

the code to generate no. of arrays from one is working..I'm try to make some change to it like below

```
Function myarray(ByVal arra1() As Integer, ByVal arran() As Integer, ByVal arrNumber As Integer) As Integer()

    arran = arra1.Clone()
    For i As Integer = 0 To arra1.Length - 1
        If i = (arrNumber - 1) Then ' IF arrNumber is 1 then +1 to index 0, If it is 2 then +1 to index 1
            arran(i) = arra1(i) + 1
            'If there are two duplicate value make on of them zero at a time
            For k = 0 To arran.Length - 1
                For j = k + 1 To arran.Length - 1
                    If arran(k) = arran(j) Then
                        arran(k) = 0
                    End If
                    'make any value great than 11 zero
                    If arran(i) > 11 Then
                        arran(i) = 0
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Else
            arran(i) = arra1(i)
        End If
    Next
    'Print the array
    For i = 0 To arran.Length - 1
        Console.Write(arran(i) & " ")

    Next

    Console.WriteLine()
    Return arran

End Function
```

what I really need is to decompose for example {1,4,5,5} to be {1,4,0,5} and then {1,4,5,0} the above code generate only {1,4,0,5}

Comment: _" {1,4,5,5} to be {1,4,0,5}"_ Can you explain this further? Also, if above generates {1,4,0,5} it seems to work.

Comment: well,this function generate arrays from one array be adding 1 to each element at a time ,but if any generating array contains the same value twice it must become two arrays by replace  each of these values   with zero value but each one at a time

Comment: So after duplicates and numbers greater than 11 are set to 0, you want to sort the array into numerical order with any zeros at the end?

Comment: @ David Wilson not exactly , let say that I have this array{2,1,3} the array that will be generated are{3,1,3} ,{ 2,2,3},{2,1,4} ,but what I need as a final result is to decomposed the first  array to be{3,1,0} and {0,1,3} and the second one to be{0,2,3}and {2,0,3} ..and the condition of greater than 11 for example should be considered always.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I believe the following code will do what you want. Based on your comments, I've changed the function to return *all* resulting arrays as an array of arrays, rather than requiring the index to change as an input and returning one array. I also ignored matches of 0, as the conditions you describe don't seem designed to handle them. Because of it's recursion, I think this approach will successfully handle input such as `{3, 3, 3, 3}`.

```
Public Function jaggedArray(ByVal inputArray() As Integer) As Integer()()
    If inputArray Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    Else
        Dim resultArrays()(), i, j As Integer
        Dim arrayMax As Integer = inputArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        If arrayMax = 0 Then    'prevents errors later if only one number passed
            ReDim resultArrays(0)
            If inputArray(0) > 11 Then
                resultArrays(0) = {1}
            ElseIf inputArray(0) = 11 Then
                resultArrays(0) = {0}
            Else
                resultArrays(0) = {inputArray(0) + 1}
            End If
            Return resultArrays
        End If
        For i = 0 To arrayMax
            Dim tempArray() As Integer = inputArray.Clone
            For j = 0 To arrayMax
                If tempArray(j) > 11 Then
                    tempArray(j) = 0
                End If
            Next
            If tempArray(i) = 11 Then
                tempArray(i) = 0
            Else
                tempArray(i) += 1
            End If
            splitArray(resultArrays, tempArray)
        Next
        Return resultArrays
    End If
End Function
Private Sub splitArray(ByRef arrayList()() As Integer, ByVal sourceArray() As Integer)
    Dim x, y As Integer 'positions of matching numbers
    If isValid(sourceArray, x, y) Then
        If arrayList Is Nothing Then
            ReDim arrayList(0)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve arrayList(arrayList.Length)
        End If
        arrayList(arrayList.GetUpperBound(0)) = sourceArray
    Else
        Dim xArray(), yArray() As Integer
        xArray = sourceArray.Clone
        xArray(x) = 0
        splitArray(arrayList, xArray)
        yArray = sourceArray.Clone
        yArray(y) = 0
        splitArray(arrayList, yArray)
    End If
End Sub
Private Function isValid(ByRef testArray() As Integer, ByRef match1 As Integer, ByRef match2 As Integer) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To testArray.GetUpperBound(0) - 1
        If testArray(i) > 11 Then
            testArray(i) = 0
        End If
        For j As Integer = i + 1 To testArray.GetUpperBound(0)
            If testArray(j) > 11 Then
                testArray(j) = 0
            End If
            If testArray(i) = testArray(j) AndAlso testArray(i) > 0 Then    'added second test to prevent infinite recursion
                match1 = i
                match2 = j
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Next
    match1 = -1
    match2 = -1
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: thank's a lot Josh ,but when I test the code I get three errors on function (jagged array) in line(10,12,13) and condition of greater than  is necessary in my project and does not related to my question ,also the function should return array not array of arrays...honestly,I don't  know how to deal with array of arrays

Comment: @rasha, I fixed the error (I had the return values `True` and `False` reversed in the isValid function). I don't know what you mean by "condition of greater than is necessary in my project". I kept the check for `> 11` in this code. The reason I returned an array of arrays is that you indicated that you wanted *more than one result* when a match was found. If you can clarify what you're looking for (input and result) a little more, it should be very easy to convert this for you.